# Another No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile error question [.NET MAUI]

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-mac

I know there are a million other questions for this error and I've tried pretty much all of them no avail.

I try "Automatic Provisioning" as well as "Manual Provisioning" and nothing's working so far and I'd appreciate some fresh suggestions.

This is the error:
[image]

I first tried it with "Automatic Provisioning" and the settings look like this:
[image]

I try to build it in Visual Studio for Mac 17.4 (Build 2406) using `Release` and `Generic Device` settings and I end up with this error.

I then tried using "Manual Provisioning". When I select this option, I get "Bundle Signing Options" button. When I click it, I see this:
[image]

This is the entry in the `myproject.csproj` file:

[image]

And in Visual Studio > Tools > Preferences > Publishing > Apple Developer Accounts, I see this under "Provisioning Profiles":
[image]

The provisioning profile name I see in `myproject.csproj` file and under Apple Accounts match exactly.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I give you some suggestions from the following aspects:

1. To check whether the profiles matches the certificate. The BundleID  and the Sign Identity of the project should be the same as what we have chosen when creating provisioning file. I think this doc [Provision an iOS app for app store distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/provision?view=net-maui-7.0) is a good example to show the workflow of creating a provisioning file.
2. Use Xcode to download and manage the certificate and profile as Visual Studio sometimes gets trouble when syncing data. Restart Visual Studio for Mac after downloading the provisioning file. You could refer to [Download the provisioning profile on your Mac build host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0#download-the-provisioning-profile-on-your-mac-build-host)

Hope  it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the exact same issue.  I've gone around and around and nothing worked.  Then I followed the steps in the previous answer link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/provision?view=net-maui-7.0 and it worked first try.  I'm not even sure what was different than what I'd been doing, but it's working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).